# iOS/OSX Core Data - Saving to a large data set persistent store is slow and uses too much CPU

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Saving to core data usually runs all well. But I am having problems with saving records to persistent store with a large number of data set. Lets assume I have around 20,000 records in the persistent store and I then save another record, the cpu usage would shoot up to 40%-60%. The actual code is complex so I have put an easy to understand code below which replicates the problem. (The cpu usage can be seen in "Debugger Navigator" tab in xcode 5 or the "Activity Monitor" app)

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(saveTestFunction) withObject: nil];
}

-(void)saveTestFunction
{
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
     NSArray *fetchedApples = [self getObjectsFromTable:@"Apples"];
     NSError *error = nil;
     int count = [fetchedApples count];

     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
     {
          NSManagedObject *apple = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Apples" inManagedObjectContext:context];

          NSString *appleName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Apple%d",count];
          [apple setValue:appleName forKey:@"appleName"];

          count++;

          NSLog(@"Saving %d",count);
          [context save:&error]; //for testing purposes I'm saving inside a loop
          sleep(1);
     }
}
```

How should I go by to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: You save the context inside the loop for testing purposes... but is it slow also when you save outside the loop? It makes no sense to save the context for each object...

Comment: Tu undertand why it works very slow (In every iteration you do SQL INSERT INTO statement) you can use compile flag -com.apple.CodeData.SQLDebug 1

Comment: MariusFalkenbergWaldal Thats true. I have only put so if anyone wants to test it out they can CLEARLY see the spikes in CPU usage. (It'll go like 0,60%,0,60% ...)

Comment: So you're not batch saving / using a background thread?